# Access nested JSON object in AngularJS controller

Tags: json, angularjs, object, controller

I am new to AngularJS and trying to create a `$scope` for `tracks` for later usage

data.json (sample):

```
[
{
    "album": "Album name",
    "tracks": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "title": "songtitle1",
            "lyric": "lyrics1"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "title": "songtitle2",
            "lyric": "lyrics2"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

Controller

```
app.controller('lyricsCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
$http.get('data.json')
    .then(function(result) {
        $scope.albums = result.data;
        $scope.tracks = result.data.tracks;

        console.log($scope.tracks);  //Undefined...
    });
});
```

Why is `$scope.tracks` undefined?

Comment: Looks like your `data` is an array of objects that contain `track` and `album`. So, something like would work for your sample: `result.data[0].tracks`

Answer (score 2):

If your json file is as is:

```
[
    {
        "album": "Album name",
        "tracks": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "title": "songtitle1",
                "lyric": "lyrics1"
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "title": "songtitle2",
                "lyric": "lyrics2"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

We have a response of:

```
data: Array[1]
    0: Object
        album: "Album name"
        tracks: Array[2]
```

Since `data` is returned as an array you would handle like any other javascript array and access by index, so you could do a loop or if you know only 1 result is going to be returned you could use the zero index:

```
$http.get('data.json').then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
    // Assign variables
    $scope.album = result.data[0].album;
    $scope.tracks = result.data[0].tracks;
    for (var i = 0, l = $scope.tracks.length; i < l; i++) {
        console.log($scope.tracks[i].title);
    }
});
```

Comment: `$http` returns a `respose` object in the `.then` function, and `response.data` is the actual data - i.e. the top-level array object above.

Comment: @NewDev You are absolutely right, I misread and thought the OP was using `.success`. My mistake, I will correct.

Answer (score 0):

result.data is an array,So you must have to use index to access its child like:-

```
$scope.tracks = result.data[0].tracks;
```

Comment: For some reason using '[0]` throws an error live, but not locally, `TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

It should be result.data[0].tracks as data is an array

$scope.tracks = result.data[0].tracks;